# `time.h` vs `TimeLib.h` on AVR boards

Tags: time

Why do I get wrong result when using `time.h` library when using AVR boards, such Nano/Uno/Pro Micro (while when using `TimeLib.h`).

OUTPUT (for given Epoch ):

`TimeLib`: 2022-04-02 16:11:20

`time.h`: 0152-03-01 16:11:20

CODE:

```
#define CASE 1

#if CASE == 1
#include <time.h>
#elif CASE == 2
#include <TimeLib.h>
#endif

time_t bootTime = 1648915880;

void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("\nStart!");
  delay(1000);

  char clk2[40];

#if CASE == 1
  struct tm *tm = localtime(&bootTime);
  sprintf(clk2, "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", tm->tm_year, tm->tm_mon, tm->tm_mday, tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
  
#elif CASE == 2
  sprintf(clk2, "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", year(bootTime), month(bootTime), day(bootTime), hour(bootTime), minute(bootTime), second(bootTime));
#endif
  Serial.println(clk2);
}

void loop()
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Comment: `localtime()` requires a timezone to be set. No idea how you set that. Use `gmtime()` instead to get the UTC (GMT) time which has no timezone.

Comment: well for that, I guessed it'll take TZ=0, or any default, no-TZ value.

Comment: Never guess anything. The problem with these functions is they grew up on UNIX (or Linux) where the OS provides things like the selected timezone. How avr-libc handles these things I have no clue.

Comment: in time.h tm struct the year starts in 1900 and the moths are 0 to 11.

Comment: @Juraj, yes- that I know, but year `153` while we are 2022, strikes a bit odd. Also subtracting few seconds `bootTime`, yielded a non rational change in result.

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming the avr-libc "epoch" is the same as the UNIX "epoch". It isn't. According to [the manual](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__time.html#gaa9336f97d394e8e02d97b9ff4fb0aca2):

> Though not specified in the standard, it is often expected that time_t is a signed integer representing an offset in seconds from Midnight Jan 1 1970... i.e. 'Unix time'. **This implementation uses an unsigned 32 bit integer offset from Midnight Jan 1 2000.** The use of this 'epoch' helps to simplify the conversion functions, while the 32 bit value allows time to be properly represented until Tue Feb 7 06:28:15 2136 UTC. The macros UNIX_OFFSET and NTP_OFFSET are defined to assist in converting to and from Unix and NTP time stamps.

So you need to subtract the `UNIX_OFFSET` from your time value before passing it to any avr-libc functions.

Also you should initialize the time system with `set_zone()` and similar functions.